# How is this query using a window function returning multiple results per key?

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have written the following query

```
SELECT
    data.id,
    LAST_VALUE(data.access_type) OVER (
        PARTITION BY data.id
        ORDER BY CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP)
    ) AS access_type,
    LAST_VALUE(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY data.id
        ORDER BY CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP)
    ) AS access_type_timestamp
FROM
    table
```

where `data` is a struct.

I am expecting this to return one row per `id` with the most recent `access_type` and `ts` for that `id`. However, it is still sometimes returning multiple rows per `id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Window functions are applied to each row of the table and do not affect the number of rows returned. Use `SELECT DISTINCT ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT`.  I would suggest `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    data.id,
    FIRST_VALUE(data.access_type) OVER (
        PARTITION BY data.id
        ORDER BY CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP) DESC
    ) AS access_type,
    FIRST_VALUE(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP)) OVER (
        PARTITION BY data.id
        ORDER BY CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP) DESC
    ) AS access_type_timestamp
FROM table;
```

Window functions not reduce the number of rows.

Also, I would assume that whatever `ts` is that it sorts the same way as a timestamp, so this can be simplified.  Also, the second is just `MAX()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT data.id,
       FIRST_VALUE(data.access_type) OVER (PARTITION BY data.id
                                           ORDER BY ts DESC
                                          ) AS access_type,
       MAX(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(ts) AS TIMESTAMP)) OVER (PARTITION BY data.id) AS access_type_timestamp
FROM table;
```

If you do use `LAST_VALUE()` you need a windowing clause:

```
LAST_VALUE(data.access_type) OVER (PARTITION BY data.id
                                   ORDER BY ts
                                   ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                 ) AS access_type
```

The default windowing clause with `ORDER BY` is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` -- and that has a nasty habit of causing `LAST_VALUE()` to simply return the value in the current row.